# how to reset radio field option of pdf form using pdfbox java

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-form

How can I set each radio button value of a radio field in a pdf form using **pdfbox** java.

I am able to get all the form value from the pdf form but my question is how can I set value for each radio box and create an new pdf form.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking one or two questions? I.e. how to set a value and how to create a form? Is it is two, then please create two questions. If it is one, please clarify. Also look at the examples in the source code download.

Comment: I am asking just one question, I can create a PDF form but, my question is how can I edit a pdf form, I just want to edit all the radio button values.

Comment: To set button set just call setValue with the appropriate value, i.e. "a", "b", "c" or whatever the values are. If you don't know what the values are either share it here, or inspect the PDF with PDFDebugger or set the values manually in Adobe Reader and call getValue().

Comment: How can I get all the kids under a radio group and how can I set the value of each kid.

Comment: pdfFields.getKids(); is not working. Is there any alternative so that I can get all the kids under a group radio field?

Comment: You can get all the kids with getWidgets(). However you don't need that, you can call setValue on the parent. What version of PDFBox are you using?

Comment: I am currently using 2.0

Comment: `List<PDAnnotationWidget> kids = ((PDRadioButton) field).getWidgets(); for (Iterator it = kids.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                            Object kid = it.next();
                            PDRadioButton radio = (PDRadioButton) kid;
                            String Name = radio.getWidgets().get(0).toString();
                             System.out.println("hi");
                             System.out.println(Name);
                             
                        }`

Comment: This is the code I am using, but it is not working

Comment: Which 2.0 version? 2.0.4 hopefully. You need to do setValue() like this: `((PDRadioButton) field).setValue()`.

Comment: I think you're not getting my actual question, suppose for one question there are 2 options like if the question is Please select your gender the option will be male or female, so here for this example there are two radio field one is male and other one is female, I just want to change value of those two options. Here I want to change male to M and female to F. Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: try this: `COSDictionary ap = (COSDictionary) widget.getCOSObject().getItem(COSName.AP);
COSDictionary apN = (COSDictionary) ap.getItem(COSName.N);
COSBase onItem = apN.getItem(COSName.getPDFName("male"));
apN.removeItem(COSName.getPDFName("male"));
apN.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("M"), onItem);
COSDictionary apD = (COSDictionary) ap.getItem(COSName.D); onItem = apD.getItem(COSName.getPDFName("male"));
apD.removeItem(COSName.getPDFName("male"));
apD.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("M"), onItem);` this assumes that there are N and D entries.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this code and let you know the result.

Comment: Is there any way to get those N and D entries?

Comment: I don't understand the question. My code shows how to get these. There is another high level way `widget.getAppearance().getNormalAppearance()` and ` widget.getAppearance().getDownAppearance()` but I'm not sure if this is correct and can't answer without having your PDF.